# WilliamChart gradient colour issue

Tags: java, android

I'm using WilliamChart and having a little trouble with setting the gradient colour. I'm hoping it's something simple I've missed but I've been staring at it for hours and making no progress. Please help.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
    int[] pdCol = new int[] {Color.parseColor("#A1D949"), Color.parseColor("#ff0000")};

    float[] pdVals = new float[] {0, 20};

    pdBar.setGradientColor(pdCol, pdVals);
```

The effect I'm getting is that the colour gradient is spread entirely over the height of the displayed bar instead of the the maximum potential height.

The sample I've provided ranges from yellowish to red. This should be extended from 0 to 20 on the chart. So a value of 10 would range from yellow to an orange colour. For some reason, no matter what value is displayed, the bar runs from yellow to red.

I hope I've managed to explain myself and that someone has a solution.

Thanks.

[image]

Here's a screenshot. As you can see, the colour is displaying in it's full range even though the value is only 4.7. I didn't want it to reach the red colour until the value was much nearer to 20.

Comment: Your snippet looks good. Though I'm not sure I understood the problem, can you show a screenshot?

Comment: screenshot added. I hope you can help. :)

Comment: It looks just fine, I think you haven't understood how does gradient works. I would recommend you to see a simple Android sample of LinearGradient.